# Pytorch automatic mixed precision (amp) backward getting slower over the batches

Tags: pytorch

Does anyone have the same problem as mine when enabling pytorch amp, the training over batches are getting slower and slower? Sometimes it starts with the 9th batch.

I found that the slower is due to

`scaler.scale(loss).backward()`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It might be better to post it on PyTorch's GitHub issues as you would get better information there (since this is a fairly recently introduced feature).